How to get the each unique data from one column
I have table like this below,
ID value
1  test
2  test
3  trouble
4  trouble
5  test
6  ok
5  trouble

This value column has three genres test trouble ok
Now I want to get the unique array such as ['test','trouble','ok'] (any order is fine)
How can I do this?

Assuming you're using Django, as the question is tagged with Django this is very easy to do.
models.py
class Entry(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100) 

views.py
unique_values = Entry.objects.values_list('value', flat=True).distinct()
unique_values_list = list(unique_values)

